# Gravitational work

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, gravity, forces, work

As far as I know gravitational work is independent from the path of the object, and I have an object that goes up on a inclined plane to a certain height, and than, after the object reaches the edge of the plane it falls back to the initial height, but on the opposed end of the plane, in that case, isn't the mechanical work equal to 0?

Comment: The change in gravitational potential energy between two points is independant of the path between them, but this does not mean the net work must be zero. For example your object starts with no kinetic energy but ends up with non-zero kinetic energy (well, until the contact with the ground stops it). There may also have been work done on internal degrees of freedom in the object. For us to answer your question you'll need to be a lot more specific about precisely what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Let there be an inclined plane , inclined at $\theta$ . Suppose there is a block of mass $m$ which will be concerned here. Let acceleration due to gravity be $g$.

At any moment, the component of gravity that opposes the block 's ascent is $-gsin\theta$. Thus, total force by the earth on the block is $-mgsin\theta$ . In order to atleast move the block with constant velocity, you have to work against the gravity. There work done against gravity is $$W_{app} = mgsin\theta \cdot{l}$$ where $l$ is the length of the inclined plane. Now potential energy gained by the block $$ PE = mgh \implies mglsin\theta$$ where $h$ is the height of the block from the ground. Now the block is fallen by you downward . Since in this case ,  the block is stationary before & after the fall , by **Work-kinetic energy theorem** ,the work done by the gravitational field will be the negative of the work done by you to descend it downward to the ground . Therefore $$W_{app} = - mglsin\theta$$. Thus, total mechanical work done by you is zero. Simple!

But if you move up the block with force greater than the gravitational force, the excess force will accelerate the block acquiring it kinetic energy. When it reaches the top-point of the plane, it has still kinetic energy. Thus by **Work-kinetic energy theorem**, the work done by you to descend the block will not be equal to the work done by the gravity. Thus ,the net mechanical work done by you will not be zero.